# Sending/receiving SMS and USSD dialing on HP ProBook 4530s w/ SIM card

Tags: networking, laptop, sms, messaging

I have an HP ProBook 4530s that has an inbuilt sim card slot. I have been able to activate Cellular data usage meaning I can use my sim card data to access the internet. What I am unable to do is respond to text messages and do [USSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data) requests. I have the Microsoft Messaging software; with it, I can only read received messages but i can not reply.

What can i do to enable text messaging and USSD dialing or is it not possible?

Comment: have you checked with your carrier to see if they have a Windows app for this? Here's two... https://www.smsdeliverer.com/desktop_software.html http://support.black-it.eu/en/products/mobile%20broadband%20sms%20toolkit/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Store page for Microsoft Messaging](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-messaging/9wzdncrfjbq6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) indicates texting via PC does not work:

> Note: The PC version of this app only shows SMS texts from your mobile
> operator about your data plan (billing, data limits, etc.), and only
> on devices built for high-speed wireless data (LTE). It can also show
> messages you've sent and received from apps such as Skype via SMS
> relay. It can't send texts.

I'm not sure what USSD is so I can't speak to that

Comment: thanks a lot for that information. So is there a software i can use for sending text messages? And maybe for dialing also?

Comment: No idea, no experience in this area just good at internet searching. Here is some links I found, good luck.
https://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp
http://www.sms-integration.com/how-to-send-sms-with-a-gsm-modem-55.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167470/how-to-receive-an-sms-in-a-desktop-pc
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208393/what-software-hardware-is-needed-to-receive-and-respond-to-sms-from-multiple-m